# PostgreSQL 1 master, multiple slave replication over slow links

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a current use case in which remote computers query a central PostgreSQL database over a internet connection (read-only). We would like to implement a "stand-alone" system for these terminals so that they will still be usable when internet connection is not available.
Replication will have to be done over a slow (~10 Mbps) link.

It is only important that the data can be accessed read-only, it is not a problem if the data is somewhat outdated.

My current solution would be to install a PostgreSQL database on the remote computer which replicate the master server over the internet. The software will then query the local database. Based on [the information from postgreSQL](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling) (especially [this presentation](http://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/replication.pdf)) [Slony](http://slony.info/) seems to be the best solution. Is this true or are there other, better/simpler solution like streaming replication?